# coercing to Unicode Django

Tags: django

I'm building a sample Django application that collects few input for Products and its picture..

I have integrated the Product model with forms and trying to add new products through Django admin...

I get the following error, when I try to create a new product..

Error:

```
TypeError at /admin/catalog/product/add/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found


Request Method:
POST 

Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/catalog/product/add/ 

Django Version:
1.4.3 

Exception Type:
TypeError 

Exception Value:
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found


Exception Location:
c:\python27\lib\ntpath.py in abspath, line 471
```

Code:

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True,help_text="Unique value for product page URL, created from name.")
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2,blank=True,default=0.00)
    #image = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_bestseller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255,help_text="Comma-delimited set of SEO Keywords for meta tag")
    meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=255,help_text="Content for description meta tag")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/products/main')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/products/thumbnails')
    image_caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products'
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('catalog_product',(),{'product_slug':self.slug})
    @property    
    def sale_price(self):
        if self.old_price > self.price:
            return self.price
        else:
            return None
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "static/",
```

Request object:

```
GET

No GET data

POST


Variable

Value


sku u'239'

meta_description u'iphone'

meta_keywords u'Iphone'

name u'Apple iphone'

_save u'Save'

is_active u'on'

price u'239'

description u'Iphone'

old_price u'200'

slug u'apple_iphone'

image_caption u'phone'

csrfmiddlewaretoken u'SuO3uQ5SFZ0bo153CXIcIXPcmnv5hHsn'

brand u'apple'

categories u'1'

quantity u'1'


FILES


Variable

Value


image <InMemoryUploadedFile: snip.PNG (image/png)>

thumbnail <InMemoryUploadedFile: snip.PNG (image/png)>
```

Is there a problem uploading a png file in Image object?

Comment: Is product your only model class?

Comment: It got fixed, once I added this piece of line--CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8')).replace('\\','/')...